# How can I find the first occurrence of an element using getBy*?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

My component has two similar forms (two forms with username/password fields), and two `Submit` buttons with the text 'Submit'. In order to test the submit handler, I'm mocking the type event for the form fields and then the clicking of the submit button like the following:

```
  it('test submit handler', async () => {
    const myProvider = ({children}) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
    render(<MyComponent />, {wrapper: myProvider});
    expect(await screen.findByText('username')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(await screen.findByText('password')).toBeTruthy();
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText('username'), 'someusername');
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText('password'), 'somepassword');
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Submit'));
    await waitFor(() => expect(onSubmit).toBeCalledTimes(1));
  });
});
```

Doing this results in the error `TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements with the text: Submit`. I looked up the docs for the `getBy*` methods and looks like they account for either the first element found or [in case there's multiple](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#getby), they throw an error, which is what's happening here. These two forms have different handler functions and I'd like to test that the two functions are being called on submit. What would be a good way to get access to the first occurrence of this `Submit` button?

I tried replacing the `getByText` with `findByText` but that results in returning a `Promise { <pending> }`, awaiting which results in the same `TestingLibraryElementError` error mentioned above.

Comment: Try `fireEvent.click(screen.getAllByText('Submit')[0])`

Comment: this is super late but thanks a lot for helping with this. Your answer was the solution.

Comment: thank you both, for asking and aswering! It was the solution

Answer (score 8):

In 2022, you use the [userEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/) package as it simulates real user behaviour:

`userEvent.click(screen.getAllByText('Submit')[0])`

**Bonus:** It's also better to find things by role as it ensures your code is accessibility friendly:

`userEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole('button', { name: 'Submit'})[0])`